# some of my code is being skipped over , why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

is there a reason why VS studio 2022 debugger is skipping lines of code?

i have tried

- Breakpoints but they still get skipped over
- I already un-ticked "just my code" in the debug settings

  `public TextLogger(){  _ = Task.Run(() => LogAsync(filePath, _LogQue, tokenSource.Token));}`

  ```
        private static async Task LogAsync(string FilePath, BufferBlock<LogInformations> que,CancellationToken token)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("In LogAsync ");
               using var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(FilePath,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
               Console.WriteLine("Still in logAsync ");
               while (true)
               {
                   try
                   { 
                       var logItem = await que.ReceiveAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                       string formattedMessage = CreateMessage(logItem, true);
                       Console.WriteLine("after create message.");
                       await sw.WriteAsync(formattedMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

                   }
                   catch (OperationCanceledException)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
                   }
               }


           }
  ```

where the console output is:

> In LogAsync

i used a breakpoint and it steps into:

```
 using var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(FilePath,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
```

then seems to exit the method for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you get an exception while creating the StreamWriter. This would end the Task and you would not see it since you have no 'await' or '.Wait'.
Have a look at the events in the Diagnostics info from Visual Studio just after the debugger has 'exited' the method.

Comment: That is almost certainly what's happening.

Comment: @JohanDonne funny enough i dont get an exception

Comment: @asuracode - to be sure, did you try wrapping the using statement in a 'try..catch' block to check if an exception was caught?